How can I run tests in the specific order with the record flag set to true, without renaming files or folders sequentially
I have multiple tests in different folders, and I want to execute them in the specific order when the record flag is set to true, so I can record the test run in the Cypress Cloud. How can I implement this without needing to rename the folders and files sequentially?
Example:
// This is my tests that I want execute them in this order
// testOrder.js
module.exports = [
'cypress/e2e/folder1/testA.cy.ts',
'cypress/e2e/folder3/testD.cy.ts',
'cypress/e2e/folder1/testB.cy.ts',
'cypress/e2e/folder2/testC.cy.ts',

];
//Cypress.config.ts
const testOrder = require('./testOrder');
module.exports = {
 e2e: 
 {
specPattern: testOrder,
record: true,
projectId: 'XXX'  //to record the results in Cypress cloud
 },
};

When Cypress runs tests with the --record flag set to true, it does not execution order of tests based on our specific order. How can I resolve this issue?

in my opinion this is falsely flagged as a duplicate as imo it's different than the suggested answer. While the suggested answer would still work it may not be the solution you would want. The only way that i would know where you can change the order of the tests is by changing your "specPattern" in your cypress config to a "testFiles", an example would be: testFiles: ['cypress/integration/test4.js','cypress/integration/test2.js','cypress/integration/test3.js','cypress/integration/test1.js'],
(this is an example, it would then do test4 first, then test2, test3 and lastly test1.

No, testFiles is no longer valid it has been replaced by specfiles. Using either of them is bad for Cypress cloud due to parallelization (this is what OP is saying). The only current solution is given in the linked answer.
